# Naive Gaussian elimination

Tags: c++, double, gaussian

While performing the naive gaussian elimination in C++, i can get a upper triangular matrix, but it doesn't work when the system of equation is more than 5*5 . any idea why this might be happening? i am using double as data type for the coefficients.

```
double factor =0;
    for(int k=0;k<(count-1);k++){
        for(int i=(k+1);i<count;i++){

            factor = (doubleCoefficient[i][k])/(doubleCoefficient[k][k]);

            for(int j=0;j<count;j++){
                doubleCoefficient[i][j] -= (doubleCoefficient[k][j]*factor);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: shouldn t you check that abs(doubleCoefficient{[k][k])>tol?

Comment: I don't think it causes it error? does it?

Comment: @user3504305 Please provide an example fail case.

Comment: 1 1 -2 1 3 -1 4 ||
2 -1 1 2 1 -3 20 ||
1 3 -2 -1 2 1 -15 ||
5 2 -1 -1 2 1 -3 ||
-3 -1 2 3 1 3 16 ||
4 3 1 -6 -3 -2 -27 ||

Comment: @user3504305 That input matrix is not square. It has 6 rows but 7 columns. What happens with e.g. a 6x6 matrix?